# Compare values of a specific column to different files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have a dataframe called `data` it's have 2 columns as follows:

```
color  fruitN
red    apple
yellow orange
blue   banana
green  avocado
```

Also, I have 3 different files of one columns; each contain list of fruits as follows:

```
file1
akee
apricot
avocado

file2
avocado
bilberry
banana
blackberry

file3
blackberry
coconut
cranberry
```

I need to create another dataframe called `type` that have # of rows equal the same as `data`= 4, and # of columns equal same as the number of files = 3

I need to check each fruit in column fruitN of the dataframe `data` if it's exist in first file, put 1 in first row first column and continue checking in file2 and file3. So, the output dataframe `type` should be like that:

```
c1 c2 c3
0  0  0
0  0  0
0  1  0
1  1  0
```

Then, concatenated with `data` to be like this:

```
color  fruitN c1 c2 c3
red    apple  0  0  0
yellow orange 0  0  0
blue   banana 0  1  0
green  avocado 1 1  0
```

I'm beginner with python, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what have you tried, perhaps show us some sample code? and i think color for banana should be yellow, while that for orange should be orange. just saying.

Comment: I don't know how to do it exactly, and yeah for the colors but it just an example to show the idea @teng

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `isin`

```
l=[f1,f2,f3]
for x,y in enumerate(l):
    df['c'+str(x+1)]=df.fruitN.isin(y.iloc[:,0].tolist()).astype(int)

df
Out[144]: 
    color   fruitN  c1  c2  c3
0     red    apple   0   0   0
1  yellow   orange   0   0   0
2    blue   banana   0   1   0
3   green  avocado   1   1   0
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this:

```
data.loc[:, 'c1'] = np.where(data['fruitN'].isin(file1.values(), 1, 0)
```

That should create c1, repeat to create the other two columns. At the end all the information you want will be in dataframe data.

You might need to import numpy

```
import numpy as pd
```

Answer (score 0):

At first create the data-frames like:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame(data=[["red", "apple"], ["yellow", "orange"], ["blue", "banana"], ["green", "avocado"]],
                    columns=["color", "fruitN"])
data = data.set_index("fruitN")
file_1 = ["akee", "apricot", "avocado"]
file_2 = ["avocado", "bilberry", "banana", "blackberry"]
file_3 = ["blackberry", "coconut", "cranberry"]
file_1_df = pd.DataFrame(data=[1] * len(file_1), index=file_1, columns=["type_1"])
file_2_df = pd.DataFrame(data=[1] * len(file_2), index=file_2, columns=["type_2"])
file_3_df = pd.DataFrame(data=[1] * len(file_3), index=file_3, columns=["type_3"])
```

then concatenate them with corresponding axis and set the sort to false:

```
data_concat = pd.concat([data, file_1_df, file_2_df, file_3_df], axis=1, sort=False).fillna(0)
```

then pick the right indices and reformat result data as you like, I did it to get exactly what you mentioned that you need:

```
res = data_concat.loc[["apple", "orange", "banana", "avocado"]]
res.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
res.columns = ["fruitN", "color", "type_1", "type_2", "type_3"]
res = res.ix[:, ["color", "fruitN", "type_1", "type_2", "type_3"]]

print(res)
```

it gives:

```
    color   fruitN  type_1  type_2  type_3
0     red    apple     0.0     0.0     0.0
1  yellow   orange     0.0     0.0     0.0
2    blue   banana     0.0     1.0     0.0
3   green  avocado     1.0     1.0     0.0
```

I hope this may help you.

Comment: It's too specific